# difference between interface inheritance and composition with interface

Tags: oop, inheritance, interface, composition

Q1: What is the difference in philosophy while designing OOP code using "interface inheritance" and "composition with interface"? (Please focus on dealing with interface part ,as I am aware of inheritance and composition and why composition is favored over inheritance).

Q2: Any use case scenario when interface inheritance should be favored over composition or composition+interface?

P.S. Focus should be in the role of interface in inheritance and composition.And any addition cue dealing with related design will be much appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a language tag like ``java`` or ``C#`` ... also, interfaces *can* be inherited by interfaces (in the proposed languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A1

You can say that *interface inheritance* is declarative, because it only states what interfaces should look like:

```
public IDerivedInterface : ISomeOtherInterface { /*...*/ }
```

These interfaces still have no behaviour, only **shape**.

*Composition with interfaces*, on the other hand, is a way to assemble **implementations**.

```
public Foo DoFoo(Bar bar)
{
    var qux = this.baz.Corge(bar); // baz is IBaz, an interface
    var garply = this.grault.Waldo(qux); // grault is IGrault, another interface
    return garply.ToFoo();
}
```

This `DoFoo` method **composes** `IBaz` and `IGrault`. One, or both, of these interfaces can be defined as stand-alone interfaces, or intherited interfaces - the `DoFoo` method doesn't care.

## A2

As the above answer explains, *interface inheritance* and *composition* are two **independent** concerns, so it makes no sense to favour one over the other. They can coexist, but they don't have to.